# Dynamic Search from beginning of word Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a list of items that I'm trying to filter with an input using the following function. It already works, but I'm trying to modify it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
var $result = $(".whoSr");

$("#whossearch").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
    if (val === "")
        $result.show();
    else {
        $result.hide();
        $result.filter(function() {
            return -1 != $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val);
        }).show();
    }
});
});

</script>

<input id="whossearch" type="text" />

<a href="#" class="whoSr">Ketchup</a>

<a href="#" class="whoSr">Hummingbirds</a>
```

This is a modified version of a function I found on here. But I'm trying to make it search from only the beginning of the word. For example: I have the words Ketchup and Hummingbirds. If I search "hu" now it will return both of these words because "hu" is in both of them. But I only want it to search in order from the beginning of the word.

Perhaps this entire method should be scrapped for something else...

Comment: `return $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val) === 0;`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm not really clear about this line though, so I need to hit the books I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return -1 != $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val);
```

change this to

```
return 0 === $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val);
```